# Load data from CSV to AGE Graph Vertices

Tags: graph-databases, apache-age

I am facing this error while trying to load data from cities.csv file:

```
test=# SELECT load_labels_from_file('community_test',
                             'City',
                             '/home/muneeb/cities.csv');
ERROR:  label_id must be 1 .. 65535
test=#
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Only provide values between 1 and 65535 ?   (which is not clear from your question)

Comment: My bad, I created label of named Country instead of City. I used SELECT create_vlabel('graph','City'); to create vertex label and it worked. Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see the error message suggests that the label_id must be in the range of 1 to 65535. This could be due to a patch for the PG11 version needing to be applied here. Make sure that your CSV file is formatted correctly.

I have found a similar issue on the apache age GitHub repository. Have look on
[this](https://Make%20sure%20that%20your%20CSV%20file%20is%20formatted%20correctly.).

.

Answer (score 0):

The function `load_labels_from_file` internally extracts the `label_id` from the label provided in the argument for inserting CSV data into underlying postgres table, so if the label does not exist then the `label_id` is 0 which is why the error is thrown.
First create the label if it does not exist as

```
SELECT create_vlabel('agload_test_graph', 'Country')
WHERE _label_id('agload_test_graph', 'Country') = 0;
```

and then load data as:

```
SELECT load_labels_from_file('community_test',
                         'City',
                         '/home/muneeb/cities.csv');
```